# composer PSR4 autoloading issue

Tags: php, oop, composer-php, autoload, psr-4

I am trying to implement PSR-4 autoloading in my project.  It is an existing application I have inherited that doesn't currently use OOP (it's all scripted), but I am hoping to refactor over time to use OOP, and PSR-4 is crucial for me as it will end up being a large project.

At this present time we do not rely on any external libraries (old application entirely written in-house), so composer is ONLY being used for autoloading at this moment in time, but will use third-party packages eventually such as phpunit.

My app structure on my server looks like this:

```
/var/www/appurl/
│   composer.json
│  
├───htdocs
│   ├───AppName
│   │   ├───admin
│   │   │       authenticated.php
│   │   │       init.php
│   │   │       login.php
│   │   │       
│   │   └───php
│   │       └───search.php
│   └───Framework
│       ├───Helpers
│       │   └───OSHelpers.php
└───vendor
    │   autoload.php
    │  
    └───composer
            autoload_classmap.php
            autoload_namespaces.php
            autoload_psr4.php
            autoload_real.php
            ClassLoader.php
```

composer.json:

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
           "Framework\\": "htdocs/Framework"
        }
    }
}
```

login.php calls authenticated.php when a user successfully logs in, and authenticated calls my init.php script which contains:

```
<?php

require_once('../../../vendor/autoload.php');

?>
```

it is search.php that has the error. The user is redirected to search.php when they are authenticated.

search.php has the lines:

```
 use Framework\Helpers\OSHelpers;
 $current_os = OSHelpers::GetConciseOSFromUserAgent($user_agent);
```

OSHelpers.php is namedspaced as: **namespace Framework\Helpers;**

the static call to OSHelpers works fine if **require_once** is used, but the 2nd line where I define $current_os is where it appears to be failing.

The error I receive is:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Framework\Helpers\OSHelpers' not found in /var/www/appurl/htdocs/AppName/php/search.php on line 829
```

I'm at a bit of a loss about why it does this?  When I follow the example in this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VGSerlMoIrY) my example app works fine, but trying to replicate this in a slightly more complicated structure is giving me problems.

I have done composer dump-autoload -o, and looking within the vendor directory shows that my classes are defined correctly.  From vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php:

```
'Framework\\Helpers\\OSHelpers' => $baseDir . '/htdocs/Framework/Helpers/OSHelpers.php',
```

Comment: When you say 'script calls some other script' and 'redirected' what do you mean exactly? Also it appears your question is missing the code of init.php

Comment: Apologies - init.php:  

<?php

require_once('../../../vendor/autoload.php');
?>

login.php POSTs to authenticated.php, and authenticated.php uses a GET to load search.php.

Comment: @weirdan, you have made me think, and I have copied  `require_once('../../../vendor/autoload.php'` and added it to search.php and I no longer get the error, so maybe there is something I'm missing to only call this once in an init script?

Comment: You have to load autoloader *once per request*. And since, from the point of view of webserver, request to `search.php` is completely unrelated to previous request, it doesn't know about autoloader that you required in request to `init.php`.

You have, basically, two options:
  1. Require initialization script in every script accessible by HTTP requests (that's what older applications usually did and what you see in old tutorials around the web: `require_once "path/to/init.php";`)
  2. Or route all requests through a single script, called 'front controller'. This is what modern frameworks do.